# Search through an array of objects looking for non empty objects JS

Tags: javascript, lodash

At the core of the problem I have:

```
[
  {amount: 0, name: "", icon: "", description: ""} // default object added to array
  {amount: 1, name: "kjfhdkfjh", icon: "67", description: "dasdasd"}
]
```

I want to know how to use lodash find such that, as long as any key has a value other then `0` or `""` we are not considered "empty".

So in this case lodash find would return:

```
[
  {amount: 1, name: "kjfhdkfjh", icon: "67", description: "dasdasd"}
]
```

Or it would return undefined.

What I have is:

```
lodashFind(theArray, function(obj){
   // Now what? How do I go through the objects? 
});
```

I am not sure how to go through objects saying, as long as there is no `0` for amount and no string has `""` then return that object.

**Ideas?**

Comment: It is not clear what you wish to achieve, you should provide an example output.  You said that an object is not empty if it has at least one non-empty field, but after you say that you search for objects not containing 0 or "". It is a contradiction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `_.filter`, `_.some`, `_.all` or `_.negate` of [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#negate) to achieve this:

```
var data = [
    { name:'a', age:0 },
    { name:'b', age:1 },
    { name:'',  age:0 }
];

// lists not empty objects (with at least not empty field)
console.log(_.filter(data, _.some));
// outputs [{name:'a',age:0},{name:'b',age:1}]

// lists 'full' objects (with no empty fields)
console.log(_.filter(data, _.all));
// outputs [{name:'b',age:1}]

// lists 'empty' objects (with only empty fields)
console.log(_.filter(data, _.negate(_.some)));
// outputs [{name:'',age:0}]
```

`_.some` and `_.all` search for *truthy* values, `''` and `0` is not truthy. Namely, the following JavaScript values are falsy: `false, 0, '', null, undefined, NaN`. Every other value is truthy.

Answer (score 0):

Using just regular javascript, this is quite easy as well, just filter the array based on the objects values etc, like this

```
var arr = [
  {amount: 0, name: "", icon: "", description: ""},
  {amount: 1, name: "kjfhdkfjh", icon: "67", description: "dasdasd"}
]

arr = arr.filter(function(o) {
  return Object.keys(o).filter(function(key) {
    return o[key] != 0 && o[key].toString().trim().length > 0;
  }).length > 0;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/webjevj8/)

Comment: I asked for lodash because its more readable in 6 months when I come back to the code

Comment: @KyleAdams - I just thought I'd post a plain JS answer, as to me this is a lot more readable than the Lodash code above